# How to remove a tab attribute in ASP .NET AJAX Toolkit using Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-ajax, tabcontrol

I have tried to remove the following tag generated by the AJAX Control toolkit.
The scenario is our GUI team used the AJAX control toolkit to make the GUI but I need to move them to normal ASP .NET view tag using MultiView.

I want to remove all the __designer: attributes

Here is the code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="a" runat="server" __designer:wfdid="w540" />
<asp:DropdownList ID="a" runat="server" __designer:wfdid="w541" />
.....
<asp:DropdownList ID="a" runat="server" __designer:wfdid="w786" />
```

I tried to use the regular expression find replace in Visual Studio using:

Find:

```
:__designer\:wfdid="w{([0-9]+)}"
```

Replace with empty space

Can any regular expression expert help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*
 * Created by SharpDevelop.
 * User: box
 * Date: 2009-9-13
 * Time: 8:13
 * 
 * To change this template use Tools | Options | Coding | Edit Standard Headers.
 */
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace t1
{
    class Sample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Create a regular expression that matches a series of one
            // or more white spaces.
            string pattern = @"__designer:wfdid=""w\d+""";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

            // Declare a string consisting of text and white spaces.
            string aspCode = @"<asp:TextBox ID=""a"" runat=""server"" __designer:wfdid=""w540"" />";

            // Replace runs of white space in the input string with a
            // comma and a blank.
            string outputStr = rgx.Replace(aspCode, ", ");

            // Display the resulting string.
            Console.WriteLine("Pattern:       \"{0}\"", pattern);
            Console.WriteLine("Input string:  \"{0}\"", aspCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Output string: \"{0}\"", outputStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The program isn't needed, the Original Poster (OP) is using the the VS Find command to remove these attributes. @"__designer:wfdid=""w\d+""" will do. A nice touch is to remove an extra space after the attribute, to avoid having two spaces and increase neatness.

Comment: I see. But I have just Visual Studio 6.0 installed. ;P

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get rid of __designer:mapid="22"

use this regex

<__designer:mapid=:q

Answer (score 0):

from 'Find option' use Wildcards search :

> __designer:wfdid="*"

find All of them and replace with empty.